# Does TIBCO rvcache still exist?

Tags: tibco, tibco-rv

A few years ago I worked on a project where we used TIBCO Rendezvous Cache (rvcache) with the TIBCO messaging framework. It would cache the topics/subjects and then it would send the cache when requested. The project I'm currently on is looking to use TIBCO as a messaging system again. I was trying to explain about the rvcache that I used years ago, but now I'm unable to find much information on it. I was curious if anyone knew if it was still being used or if perhaps it was replaced with something new with a different name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rvcache is still part of TIBCO Rendezvous and can usually be found at /tibrv//bin/rvcache. You can find more information about rvcache in the [TIBCO Rendezvous documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/rendezvous/8.3.2-august-2011/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm)